# How to select and export points interactively by drawing polygons?

Tags: geocoding, export, mapping

Does anyone know how to select a large number of addresses by basically highlighting areas on a GIS map you need names & addresses for and exporting them onto a spreadsheet?? Maybe there's no such thing but it'd sure be nice to know!

Comment: What software are you using?  (Most GISes make easy work of this, by the way, so the answer to your question is "yes." But maybe you're looking for more information than that. :-)